# Why left SHIFT + E doesn't work when F3 is pressed?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, function-keys

Something odd happened today. When logging into my system (from suspension), I couldn't type a capital `e` with Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. Right <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> worked fine, as well as any other letter with Left <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I then realised <kbd>F3</kbd> was pressed (by a book). I could confirm that having <kbd>F3</kbd> pressed blocked Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> everywhere in my system (browser, office, notepad, terminal).

Exploring further, I could also find that the following don't work:

<kbd>F1</kbd> pressed: Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

<kbd>F2</kbd> pressed: Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Other Fn keys seem not to block anything.

Exploring further, this happened also in a fresh tty session, which in principle shouldn't be affected by other running applications.

Two questions:

1. is this behaviour generalised?
2. why does it happen? (to me at least)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

PS: this seems so random that I couldn't find any related post anywhere on the web.

Comment: Did you have any applications running? Please edit your question instead of replying to this comment.

Comment: So Ubuntu itself does not appear to have any shortcut (by default) linked to F3, so I am trying to determine, if you had an application in the background that was trying to capture it.  However, you made no mention that this behavior exhibited itself, while you were trying to log into your system.  Instead of replying with a comment you need to edit and clarify your question.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard, or non-Linux operating system? Is this a [Rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) issue?